# "unpoco_xxxxxxxxx" strange cookie on my site

Tags: javascript, cookies

I can't identify the js that produces this cookie which I have not found on Google. I tried to comment on the various js on the site, but I was unable to isolate it. How can I do?
the cookie is:

```
unpoco_xxxxxxxxx
```

My site is:
https://www.michelepetrelliart.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented a tracking script from this url: `https://static.getclicky.com/js`

When you look into the code (minimized) - you will find these pieces of code:
`...||_self.get_cookie('unpoco_'+site_id)))continue...` and `...(_self.get_cookie('unpoco_'+site_id)?'&upset':'')...`

You are not able to filter on this cookie on the network tab in chrome/firefox dev tools, as this cookie is set via JS after the corresponding request is finished

Comment: can i take it off?

Comment: From Documentation `https://clicky.com/help/faq/features/cookies/disable`:
`two cookies designed to lessen the load from non-paying customers may still be set ("unpoco" and "no_tracky"`

If you are not paying, you might want to remove all corresponding JS code to disable the tracker.